# Magento multiple add to cart button

Tags: magento, product, cart

I'm just new in magento development. i need multiple add to cart buttons  with quantity field on product page.

Is there any extension for this ?

**Image link**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC5NL.jpg

Please help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tried this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25926/multiple-add-to-cart-buttons-with-quantities-specified?

Comment: It's off-topic to ask for extensions on Stack Overflow. You need to ask programming-related questions here. Try posting this on http://magento.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: @Enigmativity thank you for advise but i'm looking for extension

Comment: @RedShift thank you. exapme site already using any extension for multiple add to cart button with quantity box .